# Accidentally ran command to erase volume with "no format", how can I get it back?

Tags: hard-drive, macos, disk-utility, recovery, diskutil

I accidentally ran this command and now I am missing 100gb of space, how can I get it back? All help appreciated!!

```
diskutil eraseVolume free %noformat% disk0s2
```

Terminal gives this diskutil info:
[image]

And this corestorage info:
[image]

Partitioning will only allow me to change the 68gb and not the full 250gb.

Comment: Do you want to restore the old content or do you want a new volume? Is it an external hard drive?

Comment: It is the actual computer SSD. I have a backup of everything. I just want to get the space back. After running that command I am not able to find about 100gb of free space using disk utility. I deleted a 100gb partition and since it used the %noformat% I cannot figure out how to get it back.

Answer (score 1):

The proper command to resize your main volume to completely fill your disk is:

```
diskutil resizeVolume disk0s2 0
```

Usually you have to enter a size like 249g but 0 acts as a magic number and resizes to full size (fit to fill) while moving Recovery HD automatically.

Comment: Yes I tried that before and this is the exact error I get:     
Error: -69742: The requested size change for the target disk or a related disk is too small; please try a different disk or partition, or make a larger change

Comment: `Macs-MacBook-Pro:~ mac$ diskutil resizeVolume disk0s2 0
Resizing to full size (fit to fill)
Started partitioning on disk0s2 Mac
Verifying the disk
Verifying file system
Using live mode
Performing live verification
Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume
Checking catalog file
Checking catalog hierarchy
Checking extended attributes file
File system check exit code is 0
Resizing
Error: -69742: The requested size change for the target disk or a related disk is too small; please try a different disk or partition, or make a larger change`

Comment: @JohnS. Please try `diskutil resizeVolume disk0s2 150g`. You may have to repair your volume/disk first!

Comment: Running the second command gives: `Error: -5341: MediaKit reports partition (map) too small; if you recently grew your whole-disk, you should run whole-disk repair`

Comment: I have used the built in diskutility repair function for both the partition and the disk but it does not find anything to repair..

Comment: @JohnS. You have to boot to Internet Recovery Mode or a OS X thumb drive, open Terminal and enter `diskutil repairDisk /dev/disk0` and `diskutil repairVolume /dev/disk0s2`

Comment: I will try that now, I will have to reformat I assume to repair so I will log off and logon another computer to post the results.

Comment: I have no explanation why, but running those two repair commands magically allowed me to reformat the entire 250gb drive and use 250gb of space for a time machine backup. I am restoring now and hopefully it will work. Thank you!!! @klanomath